# Separar cadena de texto en consola Linux

Tags: linux, date, línea-de-comandos, awk, grep

Tengo una cadena de texto con el formato `AñoMesDiaHoraMinutoSegundos`, ejemplo: `20190504021025`.

Necesito separar este texto por comando en Linux y agruparlo por hora entre las 02 y las 06 am sin perder la fecha ya que necesito todo el 2019.

Es decir, necesito que la siguiente cadena:

```
20190504021025
```

separarla con el siguiente formato:

```
20190504 021025
```

Para agruparlo utilizo el comando `uniq -c`

Para separarlo por rango de hora utilizo el comando `grep -E ^0[2-6]`

Pero para utilizar estos comandos necesito separar la fecha.

No sé como hacerlo.

```
grep -h "fecha" /directorio/archivo.txt | cut -b23-38
```

Hasta aquí logro rescatar la fecha y hora, pero aparece todo junto.

Comment: dado que quieres hacer dos cosas, sería bueno que proporcionaras un ejemplo claro de fichero de entrada (en el que haces "grep") así como la salida exacta que buscas

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que tienes un fichero con muchos datos, que extraes con:

```
grep "fecha" /directorio/archivo.txt | cut -b23-38
# elimino -h porque no tiene sentido aquí
```

Es decir, en aquellas líneas en las que aparece "fecha" quieres extraer los caracteres que van del 23 al 38. Esa parece que es una fecha y como tal podrías trabajarla usando `date`.

Sin embargo, dado que lo que quieres es solamente añadir un espacio entre el 8.º carácter y el siguiente, creo que es tan fácil como decir:

```
sed -r 's/^.{8}/& /'
```

Esto coge los 8 primeros caracteres y los vuelve a imprimir con un espacio a continuación. El resto de línea sigue igual.

Ejemplo:

```
$ echo "20190504021025" | sed -r 's/^.{8}/& /'
20190504 021025
```

Por tanto, todo tu comando quedaría en:

```
grep "fecha" /directorio/archivo.txt | cut -b23-38 | sed -r 's/^.{8}/& /'
```

Dado que de hecho estamos haciendo tres cosas bastante simples, sed podría hacerlo todo en un comando único:

```
sed -r '/fecha/s/^.{22}(.{8})(.{6})/\1 \2/' fichero
```

Esto lo que hace es:

- `/fecha/s/busca/sustituye/` busca las líneas que contienen "fecha" y ejecuta el comando `s/busca/sustituye/`.
- `s/^.{22}(.{8})(.{6})/\1 \2/` en esas líneas, cuenta hasta el carácter número 22. A partir de allí, recoge los siguientes bloques de 8 y 6 caracteres para imprimirlos a continuación con un espacio en el medio.

Comment: Te pasaste esto soluciono mi problema. Jamas había ocupado el comando sed. Es hora de leer un poquito más. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @comentin Si te funcionó la respuesta, puedes marcarla como la opción correcta. Si además te gustaron otras, puedes puntuarlas positivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el valor que capturas tiene siempre el mismo formato (eso es lo que especificas), puedes usar el parámetro de expansión usando el carácter `$`. Más específicamente la expansión de `substring`. Puedes leer más en el manual de `bash`, escribiendo en la consola: `man bash`.

Lo siguiente es un extracto de dicho manual: (traducción propia)

> ${parameter:offset:length}
>
> Substring Expansion.
>
> Expande hasta `length` caracteres del valor `parameter` comenzando en el caracter indicado por `offset`. ... . Si se omite `length`, la expansión del substring del valor `parameter` se realiza empezando en el caracter especificado por `offset` y se extiende hasta el final de dicho valor.
>
> ...
>
> El indexado de `subtring` es `zero-based` a menos que se utilize un parámetro posicional, en cuyo caso el índice comienza en 1 por defecto.

Dicho esto, una forma en que puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
>input=$(grep -h "fecha" /directorio/archivo.txt | cut -b23-38)
>fecha=${input:0:8}
>hora=${input:8}
```

Ahora ya tienes las variables `fecha` y `hora` sobre las cuales puedes operar.

Una captura de ejemplo:

[image: Prueba de uso]

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda

Comment: El problema es que son millones de registros. Lo que hice fue pasarlo a un txt pero el excel no me deja leerlo por que son muchos los registros. Tendré que sacarlo por semana :(

Comment: La otra opción seria agregarle un espacio, pero no se como hacerlo jejeje (novato)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que tienes millones de lineas en un archivo de texto? Y supongo deseas leer el archivo y capturar los que coincidan con tu parámetro. ¿Lo piensas escribir en otro archivo? Si complementas tu pregunta te puedo ayudar un poco más. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa Mauricio fui poco claro.

Comment: Te cuento que estoy leyendo un log completo con distintos parametros y solo estoy cortando la linea que contiene la fecha, hora y rut. El tema es que esta tan grande el archivo que se me hace imposible abrirlo en excel.

Comment: Por lo que necesito es acortar solo los registros que sean de 02 am a 6 am. Es decir 20190504021025Rut. Al cortar con el comando cut deja todo junto y no es posible aplicar un filtro (grep -E) para la hora que necesito (02 am - 6am). de minuto tengo lo he sacado de la siguiente forma: grep -h "Marca" /RUTA/archivo.log | cut -b10-19,516.523 | sort | uniq -c (me falta aplicar el filtro para la hora grep -E 0[2-6]) Todo esto necesito exportarlo a un archivo de texto para abrirlo en un excel y hacer un gráfico.